# How to get npm update to log which packages were actually updated?

Tags: node.js, npm

Currently using npm v9.1.3 on Node v16.16.0 on Windows. In older (but recent!) npm/Node versions, doing `npm update` would log to the console which specific packages were updated at the end of the process, something like (going from memory here)

```
+updated terser to 12.5.4
+updated colors to 1.2.3
[etc]
```

But now by default it just logs stuff like

```
changed 5 packages, and audited 592 packages in 34s
```

I've tried upping the `loglevel` and while that shows a bunch more info about network requests and the like, it still doesn't plainly specify which packages were actually updated like it used to.

I know I can run `npm outdated` before `update` to get a quick idea of what `update` might do, but that doesn't include indirect/subdependencies. And further I could do `npm outdated --all` but that shows a ginormous list of all possible outdated subdependencies and not just the ones that would be updated by `npm update`.

This is getting frustrating and I've taken to scouring diffs of my package-lock.json just to find out what my last `npm update` run actually did. Any suggestions? Surely there's a stupid easy way to get the old logging functionality back that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you try with `silly` log level?

Comment: `silly` prints the "changed x packages" message at the end like the rest. It does log some not-very-human-readable info that *might* contain the info I'm looking for but it's not clear. It does seem to list towards the end which folders under node_modules were modified so that helps, but with no version numbers. Certainly nothing like the concise list that used to appear in previous versions of npm like "updated package x to version y".